# iOS push notifications do not work when app is in background

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I posted this in a different question several weeks ago and did not receive any response that would help me resolve it.

I have an iOS application where I receive push notifications through APNS.

When the app is in the foreground, push notifications triggered to APNS work 100% correctly.  The correct delegate method is fired, and everything works as expected.

Now, if the user presses the home screen and goes to the iOS home screen or goes into any other app, the push notifications for my app stop working.  Upon triggering a push notification, nothing happens on the device.  If the user returns to the app (app in the foreground), push notifications start working again.

My understanding when my app is in the background, no application logic actually executes on receiving a push notification.  Therefore, I am beat in terms of how I should solve this.  It obviously cannot be a code issue.  If it was a code problem, the app would be failing to register for push notifications.  However, that's not the case since push notifications do work when my app is in the foreground.

Any ideas?

Comment: are you running on iOS7 or iOS8?

Comment: I have an a version of the app targetting iOS7 and another version targetting iOS8.  Same issue in both.

Answer (score -1):

Did you added in your `AppDelegate.m` didFinishLaunchingWithOptions method:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:(UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge | UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound | UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert)];
```

?

Comment: Yes, that is in there.